# How to solve the strange behavior of content node in view

Tags: views

I found one strange behaviour in views. Like if I click on a node title of a view table, it will take me to node page. If I click edit and save the content will save faster.

But in the view, which has an edit field link, if I click on the edit link, and try to save the same node it takes several minutes to save.

Can anyone know why is this strange behaviour is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: I've edited your question. I am still trying to make sense of it. So you added an edit link as a field to your view?

Comment: @NoSssweat: Thanks,yes and if i try edit and save to get save with this link than its takes several minutes, but if i click on node of table view and edit and save to save it takes very less time

Answer (score 1):

Saving is perceived slower because after saving (with or without overlay) it automatically redirects you to the last page you were at. Since your view takes longer to load than a single node page, saving is perceived slower.

In conclusion, the actual saving takes the same amount of time, the difference is the view page load versus the node page load.

Comment: :i have already disabled it:( while saving the node particularly it taking time i,e when we click on save button.

Comment: @neethu updated my answer.

Comment: @neethu You could try using Rules to redirect you to the node page after saving, that way it won't redirect you to the view, if you were at the view before.

Comment: understood,so ur suggesting me to create a rule for that view?is  there such options in rule?sorry if i am being dumb

Comment: or is there any way to reduce the view page load timing?

Comment: @neethu, no, a rule that executes after content is saved (saving the node).

Comment: `is there any way to reduce the view page load timing` @neethu [https://www.drupal.org/project/shadow](https://www.drupal.org/project/shadow)

Comment: It might also help you cache your View, that way it does not have to rebuild all content and the View should build faster. This trick works better in Drupal 8 where your updated node should update the View. In Drupal 7 this can lead to a View that will remain to show the old version of the node until the cache expires. Use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_content_cache to prevent that in D7.

Comment: @NoSssweat: yup i have tried with this module whenever we open the view that view will be listed shadow list and for that i have created new shadow table but its of no use

Comment: @Neograph734: thanks,butI have enabled view cache in that particular view.

Comment: @NoSssweat: last time just to click on edit link also it was the same was taking lot of time but in content page one f the field type changed from select list to auto complete i changed that given dramatical change i,e when we click on edit link in view page it loads fast and now while saving its the same now save button link slow of view

Comment: @neethu of course, because select list it has to go to the db and fetch all possible options, while using autocomplete, it will not do that until you try and type inside the box. Also, autocomplete limits the auto complete suggestions so it doesn't load all possibilities. Thus, sometimes you have to keep typing to get a possibility.

Comment: @NoSssweat: true understood but for this save  button n this view page loading not finding any option to optimize the performance issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem in view was select list filter condition and i just removed it and it fixed my problem :)

Thanks for support @NoSssweat and @Neograph734